# Geodesics of Sasaki metric

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I would like to ask the community for a reference on the following question:

*Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $(T^1M,g_S)$ be the unit tangent bundle with the Sasaki metric. Is it true that the orbits of the geodesic flow $\varphi:T^1M\longrightarrow T^1M$ are geodesics of $(T^1M,g_S)$?*

Any help/reference would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Consider a projection $\pi : (T_1M,G) \rightarrow (M,g) $ We
want to define a metric $G$. If $\widetilde{c_1} (t),\
\widetilde{c_2}(t) $ are curves starting at $(p,v)$ then we write
$\widetilde{c_i}(t)=(c_i(t),v_i(t)),\ c_i(0)=p,\ v_i(0)=v$ so that
let
$$ G(\widetilde{c_1}'(0),\widetilde{c_2}'(0)) =g(c_1'(0),c_2'(0)) +
g(\nabla_{c_1'} v_1,\nabla_{c_2'} v_2)\ \ast $$

And if $c_1(t)=p$, then we use $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\ v_1(t)$
instead of $\nabla_{c_1'} v_1$.

(2) Now we will interpret this definition. Fix a curve $c$ at
$c(0)=p\in M$. If $v(t)$ is a parallel vector field along $c(t)$
with $v(0)=v$, then define $\widetilde{c}(t)=(c(t),v(t))$ So we have
${\rm length}\ c ={\rm length}\ \widetilde{c}$. That is any curve in
$M$ can be *lift*ed into some curve of same length to any
point.

(3) If $c$ is a unit speed geodesic in $M$, then
$\widetilde{c}(t)=(c(t),c'(t))$, lift of $c$, is a geodesic in
$T_1M$ : Let $\widetilde{p}=\widetilde{c}(0),\
\widetilde{q}=\widetilde{c}(\epsilon )$ Assume that
$\widetilde{\gamma} =(\gamma (t),v(t))$ is a geodesic in $T_1M$
between two points s.t. $\gamma$ has unit speed. Hence since
$${\rm length}\ \gamma\geq {\rm length}\ c,$$ then
$\widetilde{\gamma}$ is $\widetilde{c}$